# JavaFX - Label Display

Tags: java, javafx

I have a display question

I have a Label called msg

```
msg.setText(message);
msg.getStyleClass().add(type.toString());
final FadeTransition fade= new FadeTransition(millis(100), msg);
fade.setFromValue(0.0);
fade.setToValue(100.0);
fade.playFromStart();
```

This is the existing code. I do not want fadeTransition anymore.But I want my label to be displayed.

Yet, If I remove the fade lines my Label never gets displayed. but with the FadeTransition, the label gets displayed.

Can anyone tell me why?

Observation:
I thought its because new Label was not created and tried doing it.

```
msg = new Label(" ....");
```

doesnt work.

Comment: Random guess: the style class sets the opacity to zero?

Comment: No! It doesnt touch the opacity part